# extending angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using angular-ui-boostrap's typeahead component to let people choose a person's name, or add a new name if their selection isn't present.

[image: typeahead with three two names and an 'add new' option]

Right now I modified `getMatchesAsync` with my own code:

```
      if(scope.matches.length < 4 || scope.matches.length == undefined){
        scope.matches.push({
          id: getMatchId(matches.length),
          label: 'Add New +',
          model: 'new'
        });
      }
```

But I realize this is not a good long term solution, especially when the component is updated.

Where should I put my code and how do I integrate it into the component?
Typeahead module: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js

Comment: Can't you just manipulate the source data as it comes in?

Comment: Thats a good thought but there are a couple reasons that wont work:
1. the filtering and matching is done client side.  2.I'm not actually fetching results, the list is already loaded.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case. You can still use a method in the `sourceArray` expression that returns your filtered set with optional "new" model (or a promise if you need to process asynchronously). The only difference is that you do the filtering / matching instead of typeahead

Comment: Come to think of it, typeahead doesn't do any filtering anyway. I'd just create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) that proxies [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: @Phil i was just going to suggest throwing a filter on there.. i did basically this same thing with.. `typeahead='item in items | addNew'`, or some such code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of what I suggested in the comments...

```
someModule.filter('filterWithNew', function($filter) {
    return function(array, expression, comparator) {
        var matches = $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator);

        if (matches.length < 4) {
            matches.push({
                label: 'Add new +',
                model: 'new'
            });
        }
        return matches;
    };
});
```

Then you should be able to use

```
... typeahead="name.label for name in names | filterWithNew:$viewValue"
```

Comment: Nice, this worked.  I had to also add 'full_name' with the value 'Add New +' to the hash since I specified person as person.full_name in the markup.

Comment: @Ashbury cool. I did take some liberty at guessing your data format but I figured you'd know what to do there